# View profiles need to be in same place with or without content

Tags: html, css, position

How do i get my view profile link below to stay at the same postion when all data is available i dont no how to do this with css tried bottom :0 but this didn't work any help be appreciated. I meen if you look at Gary Bennett for example i want the view profile to be at same postion for all profiles.

http://east-belfast.wsini.com/staff

Any help is greatly apreciated as always.

```
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <div id"content"  style="font-size:14px;min-height:140px;position:          relative;">

  <img src="images/profile.png" align="left" style="padding-right:5px;">

  <span style="color:#3c79ba"><?php echo $item->name;?></span><br/>
  <span><?php echo $item->job_title;?></span><br/>
  <img src="images/line.png"><br />  <?php if ($item->phone !="" ) {?> 
  <img src="images/phone.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <?php }else{?>
  <br />

  <img src="images/email.png">&nbsp;&n
  <span  style="color:#3c79ba"><?php echo $item->phone;?></span><br />
  <?php }?>
   <?php if ($item->email !="" ) {?> 
  <img src="images/email.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span  style="color:#5881b3"><?php echo $item->email;?> </span><br /> 
  <?php }else{?>
  <br />
  <?php }?>
  <br /> 
  <div style="height:10px;position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;">
  <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_staffdirectory&view=staff&id=' . (int)$item->id); ?>"> View profile
    </a>
        </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <?php


 if($counter == 2) {?>

    <br class="clearboth">

    <?

 }?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.thumbnail div { position:relative; height: 142px; } /* 142px is the height of your images, put in to make the box stretch in height if little content */
.thumbnail a { position: absolute; bottom: 0; } /* I'd add a class to this in case you want to link any other info from the container */
```